# Tengo un problema en un Programa de Escritorio, me sale este error: ImportError: cannot import name 'Literal' from 'typing'

Tags: visual-studio, python-3.7

Buenas vibras a esta hermosa comunidad, soy principiante en Python, estoy realizando un Programa de Escritorio en Visual Studio Code 1.81.1, en Windows 10 32 bits, con la version 3.7.0 de Python y al correr el programa me arroja este error:  ImportError: cannot import name 'Literal' from 'typing'

```
  from tkinter import *
```

> ```
> from tkinter import messagebox
> import customtkinter as ctk
> from Programas.Principal.programa_principal import programa_principal
> from Programas.Acceso.acceso_designer import acceso_designer
> from Programas.Acceso.acceso_registro import registroUser
>
> import util.cent_vent as util
> from Programas.Validacion.validar_user import validarConexion
>
>
> ctk.set_appearance_mode("dark") # Modes: system (default), light, dark
> ctk.set_default_color_theme("blue") # Themes: blue (default), dark-blue, green
>
> class acceso(acceso_designer):
>     
>     def __init__(self):
>         # Creación de la ventana principal
>         #self.login=acceso_designer()
>         super().__init__()
> ```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver en la imagen, en VSC me resalta los errores que segun tiene el programa, como podria resolver este problema, ya que no me deja correr el programa, estos son los programas instalados en la version de Python 3.7.0:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Existe algun problema de Compatibilidad con ellos?

Les agradeceria cualquier aporte que me podrian realizar......

Que tengan un hermoso dia........ Saludos

Comment: Hola Albin, gracias por la buena onda, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta, y lo que sea código, explicaciones, o mensajes de error, lo agregues como texto, así evitarás recibir votos negativos, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, y 
obtengas una mejor respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¡Hola! Parece que estás teniendo un problema con la importación de algún módulo o clase en tu código de Python. El error que mencionas, `ImportError: cannot import name 'Literal' from 'typing'`, suele estar relacionado con la versión de Python y las bibliotecas que estás utilizando. La clase `Literal` se introdujo en Python 3.8 y puede que estés utilizando una versión anterior de Python en tu entorno.

Dado que mencionaste que estás utilizando Python 3.7.0, es posible que el módulo typing en esta versión no contenga la clase Literal.

Para solucionar este problema, puedes intentar lo siguiente:

1. **Actualizar a una versión de Python más reciente**: Si es posible, considera actualizar a una versión más reciente de Python, como Python 3.8 o superior, que incluye la clase `Literal` en el módulo `typing`.
2. **Evitar el uso de Literal**: Si no puedes actualizar Python, y estás usando `Literal` en tu código, intenta reemplazarlo con alternativas disponibles en versiones anteriores de Python. Por ejemplo, en lugar de:

```py
from typing import Literal
```

Puedes usar:

```py
from typing import Union
```

Y luego, en lugar de utilizar `Literal`, puedes utilizar `Union` para indicar que un valor puede ser de uno de varios tipos.

3. **Verifica las bibliotecas y módulos externos**: Asegúrate de que todas las bibliotecas y módulos externos que estás utilizando sean compatibles con la versión de Python que estás utilizando.

Recuerda también asegurarte de que estás utilizando la versión correcta de Python en tu entorno de desarrollo (Visual Studio Code). Puedes verificar esto seleccionando el intérprete de Python correcto en la parte inferior derecha de la ventana de Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Muchas gracias, intentare con lo que me estas sugiriendo. Saludos

Comment: Adicional, en Python 3.7 puede instalar el módulo [typing_extensions](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/): `pip install typing_extensions` y luego en el código `from typing_extensions import Literal`. Ver [referencia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67193166/1545868).